# How to avoid polluting the current scope (with `library(...)`)

Tags: r, import, fully-qualified-naming

As a matter of long-standing policy, I avoid importing names into (aka "polluting") the current scope, and instead I use fully-qualified names when referring to items defined in a different package.

The script below shows that, in R, using qualified names is, in itself, not enough.

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

set.seed(0)

x <- local({
         x0 <- matrix(rnbinom(80, size = 5, mu = 10), nrow = 20)
         `rownames<-`(rbind(0, c(0, 0, 2, 2), x0),
                      paste("Tag", 1:(nrow(x0) + 2), sep = "."))
     })

y <- edgeR::DGEList(counts = x,
                    group = rep(1:2, each = 2),
                    lib.size = 1001:1004)

## library(edgeR)

y[1, 1]
```

The script fails with

```
Error in y[1, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
Execution halted
```

The script's only crime appears to be not having included the line `library(edgeR)` somewhere before the failing statement, since the error disappears if one un-comments the commented-out line.

This is voodoo, imho.

Is there a way to avoid the error without polluting the current scope with `library(edgeR)`?

Comment: Have a look at the modules package.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: Thanks for the suggestion, but I confess that, after quickly glancing at the `modules` website, it's not clear to me how this package would help in this case.  Would you mind elaborating a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you avoid loading the `edgeR` package, you also avoid loading the `[.DGEList` method, which is necessary to execute `y[1, 1]`.  If you prefer not to load the `edgeR` library, you'll need to call the extraction function directly:

```
edgeR::`[.DGEList`(y, 1, 1)
```

If you don't like the fully qualified syntax, you can bring in the method you need with

```
`[.DGEList` <- edgeR::`[.DGEList`
```

Then `y[1, 1]` will work as expected.  But this is another form of pollution and I'm not sure I'd recommend it as a general solution.

Comment: Thanks!  BTW, I don't consider `\`[.DGEList\` <- edgeR::\`[.DGEList\`` pollution, because it's explicit.